# Differentiate markers Android MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to differentiate between markers using Google Maps on Android. I tried several solutions presented on StackOverflow. One of them was setting a tag for a marker, and on the click marker I would retrieve that Tag (depending on which marker I clicked on), the thing is it doesn't differentiate and shows me the same Info for both markers I currently have.

Here's a portion of the code:

```
private void markUserLocationMap(final Double currentUserLatitude, final Double currentUserLongitude) {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("users").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();

                            String s = data.get("location").toString();
                            List<String> userInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
                            final String username = data.get("username").toString();
                            userInfo.add(username);
                            final String teamName = data.get("teamName").toString();
                            userInfo.add(teamName);
                            String latitude = s.substring(s.indexOf("latitude") + 9, s.indexOf(","));
                            String longitude = s.substring(s.indexOf("longitude") + 10,s.indexOf("}"));
                            double latitudeValue = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                            double longitudeValue = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

                            if(( (currentUserLatitude != latitudeValue)&& (currentUserLongitude != longitudeValue) ) && ((latitudeValue+1<=currentUserLatitude) ||(latitudeValue-100<=currentUserLatitude))  && ((longitudeValue+100<=currentUserLongitude) ||(longitudeValue-100<=currentUserLongitude)) ){ //alterar os valores, para alterar o radius
                                LatLng userInteracting = new LatLng(latitudeValue, longitudeValue); //the user that its currently being accessed
                                mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                                        .position(userInteracting)
                                        .title(username)); //para mostrar o seu nome ao clicar no marker
                                mCurrLocationMarker.setTag(userInfo);

                                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {      //mMap is a GoogleMap object
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                        Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, Pop.class);
                                        String userInfo = (mCurrLocationMarker.getTag()).toString();
                                        i.putExtra("userInfo",userInfo);

                                        startActivity(i);
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });


                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

So here I'm trying to store the userInfo I get into the tag, and then whenever I click the marker I should retrieve that specific userInfo, the thing is, as I said previously, it returns the same userInfo for both markers I have, shouldn't the tags be different between the markers? I'm reaching the userInfo by means of FireStore, and going through every user, and displaying a marker for each.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your listener

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, Pop.class);
    // Don't use the field mCurrLocationMarker, use the passed in marker object
    String userInfo = (marker.getTag()).toString();
    i.putExtra("userInfo",userInfo);
    startActivity(i);
    return false;
 }
```